# Aerospike secondary index not returning all data after upgrade

Tags: aerospike

24 hours after all data were migrated for a 3.8.2.3 to 3.9.1.1 [**upgrade**](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/upgrade/aerospike#2), some rows were missing when using a secondary index (NUMERIC) with **AQL** :

```
aql> SELECT * FROM NameSpace.set WHERE missingdata_index = 0
```

Everything was fine using the PK :

`aql>  SELECT * FROM NameSpace.set WHERE PK = 'PKVALUE'`

Notes :

- I could observ this issue for another migration 3.8.X to 3.8.2.3
- **Dropping the index and recreating it resolves the issue.**

Comment: Where migrations happening by any chance when the queries were issued?

Comment: @Meher, no all migrations were over :/

Comment: When you connect to the nodes of the cluster with asadm, and run 'info', is the cluster size on all of those what you expect, or do some seem to be having a different number?

Comment: @RonenBotzer, With Aerospike Management Console (Community Edition - 3.6.10.1), I could see Cluster Size == number of nodes (4), and Cluster visibility was green for all nodes.

If you give me the information you need to debug, I could send them to you for our next upgrade :) but it might be in a few months

Answer (score 2):

This actually may be related to an issue that was just fixed and should be available in the next release (you should be able to check for the following jira: AER-4930 in the upcoming release notes - hopefully by the end of this month).